# Why is the SQL full outer join is not presenting unmatched customers (avc_id)?

Tags: sql

I appreciate your help in advance!

The right table `avc_enr` has 108K customers (`b.avc_id`) in it. In the 2nd table (alias `a`), we have about 97K customers (`a.avc_id`).

I tried to use right, left and full outer join but every time the count of customers shows 97K rather than 108K customers (under `Total_users`)... any idea why with full outer join the count function is not counting all customers even if no common match is found between two tables?

```
with avc_enr as 
(
    select 
        dt, avc_id, service_template_name 
    from 
        hive.thor_satellite.v_nms_inventory_nmsdb_avc_service
    where 
        current_status = 'ACTIVE' and dt = 20220809
)
select 
    a.dt, a.metrics_date,
    avg(a.vsat_fl_byte_count_kbps) as AUPU_Kbps, 
    count(b.avc_id) as Total_users
from 
    hive.thor_satellite.vda_satellite_nms_performance_smts_avc_pm_throughput a
full outer join 
    avc_enr b on a.avc_id = b.avc_id and a.dt = b.dt
where 
    a.dt = 20220809
group by 
    a.dt, a.metrics_date
```

Comment: You are applying a filter the left table on your `WHERE`, which is forcing a row on that table to exists and match that condition, probably filtering the rows you want to see. I'd suggest inverting the table orders, using a `LEFT JOIN` and adding that `a.dt` filter inside the join condition.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)